# catching an exception in the right place

Tags: c++

The function Notify is going to throw an exception, where should I be catching it in this piece of code ?
Can I catch it in JobStateStatus or should it be within SubscriberAlarm or is it just a matter of choice ?

```
JobStateStatus::JobStateStatus( const EventResourcePtr& eventResource, const EventQueuePtr& eventQueue ) : JobStateSignal( eventQueue )
{
    eventResource->GetIPCMonitor()->SubscribeAlarm(STATE_STATUS, std::bind( &JobStateStatus::Notify, this, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
}

void
JobStateStatus::Notify( IPCEventPtr ipcEvent )
{
    // ...
    struct timeval now = {0,0};
    if (0 != gettimeofday(&now, NULL))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failure with gettimeofday");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You have to catch it in the peace of your code you call the function that throws

Comment: You can catch it in `main` if you want to. Would that make sense? Hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: catch it where you can recover from it. If you cannot recover from an exception to continue with "normal" program flow then there is no point in catching the exception. Though, I am afraid the question is purely opinion based

Comment: Think i will try , throw and catch it there itself. 
```
try {
  int age = 15;
  if (age >= 18) {
    cout << "Access granted - you are old enough.";
  } else {
    throw (age);
  }
}
catch (int myNum) {
  cout << "Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.\n";
  cout << "Age is: " << myNum;
} 
```

Comment: In general I would make all event handlers noexcept (and enforcing this in SubscribeAlarm), since the sender usually doesn't know what you are doing. By enforcing noexcept it is clear that the handler should catch all exceptions and handle them. So for you that would mean catch in notify

Comment: @badri Opinion - don't use exceptions for expected data validation tests; these functions should return a result; ie if you know there is going to be a age test that can fail then this is not exceptional and exceptions should not be used.